# Use of phrase ברוך הבא

Tags: prayer-book, wedding, brit-milah, pidyon-haben

Based on what I have seen I Nusach Ashkenaz siddurim such as Art Scroll and Birnbaum, among some others, I noticed the phrase ברוך הבא is used at the beginning of a *Brit* (circumcision) when welcoming the baby, and when welcoming the *chattan* (groom) to the *chuppah*.

However, I have not seen this included at a *pidyon haben* (redemption of first-born male), to welcome the baby (common ceremony procedure is that someone brings in the baby on a silver tray.) Why is it not used for this ceremony?

Could it possibly be because at a *pidyon*, nothing is physically happening to the baby and he is not directly performing any mitzvah?

Comment: [Maybe a better question.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30569207#30569207)