# Use of phrase ברוך הבא - Version #2

Tags: wedding, brit-milah

Inspired by [The previous version of my question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73246/5275)

I noticed that in Nusach Ashkenaz,  ברוך הבא is said at both a Brit as well as when the Chattan (groom) walks down the aisle toward the Chuppah.

Someone explained to me that the reason this phrase is said at a brit is to welcome the child into the "covenant" as he is about to "officially" join the Jewish nation / community.

But, why is this also said for a groom? I'm surmising (my *drash*, here) that later on during the brit ceremony we say a phrase:

> כשם שנכנס לברית כן יכנס לתורה לחופה ולמעשים טובים

A literal translation of the above is:

> "In the manner that he entered the *brit*, so shall he enter for
>   Torah, for chuppah and for good deeds"

I'm curious if any notable (i.e. a rav, commentary, Gemarah, etc.) has explained the term כשם שנכנס לברית as meaning that in the way that he **literally** entered the *brit* meaning, hearing the words ברוך הבא, so too should he enter his chuppah also hearing the same words ברוך הבא?

Comment: "Baruch Haba!" (Translation: "Welcome to the real world!!!")

Comment: @ezra Someone told me that the citation, above, was what allowed a chattan to appear in his birthday suit at the chuppah. I think the one who told me this was joking, but, I guess I'll never know.

Comment: That's very funny! I'm pretty sure he was joking. :P